# Using Postgis' Geometry type with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, geometry, postgis

I've been trying to build my first ever API project using ASP.NET Core.

Everything is going smoothly, except for one thing. Whenever I try to add a new scaffolded controller (after adding my models, of course), I get the following error:

> The property 'Favor.Coordinates' is of type 'Geometry' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

This is self-explanatory; I've got a model class with a `Geometry` type (from Postgis), which seems to be causing issues for Entity Framework.

**What have I done?**

- I have created my DB and added the Postgis extension to be able to use the Geometry data type
- I have added the `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite` package to support the `Geometry` in my project, as detailed in the following tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial
- I have added all required Npgsql extensions to use PostgreSQL with ASP.NET, and generated all model classes from the database

It's important to mention that I also added the `NetTopologySuite` package before generating my models, just as the tutorial mentions. Nevertheless, whenever I tried to add a scaffolded API controller using Entity Framework, I get the aforementioned error, despite the fact that NTS does *support* `Geometry`.

For further reference, here's the `Favor` class that the error mentions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

namespace FavorAPI.Models
{
    public partial class Favor
    {
        public Favor()
        {
            Payment = new HashSet<Payment>();
            Request = new HashSet<Request>();
        }

        public int Idfavor { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Creationtime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Happeningtime { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        public short? Estimatedtime { get; set; }
        public short? Maxpeople { get; set; }
        public short? Currentpeople { get; set; }
        public Geometry Coordinates { get; set; } //<-- Problematic!
        public int? Idstatus { get; set; }
        public int? Idposter { get; set; }
        public int? Idcategory { get; set; }

        public virtual Category IdcategoryNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Individual IdposterNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Favorstatus IdstatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Request> Request { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have also added `x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()` to my DB context. Does anyone have an idea of what could I be doing wrong? I can always add the `[NotMapped]` attribute mentioned by the error, but I *do* want this attribute to be mapped.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Creating the controllers manually (rather than through scaffolding) works and throws no errors, but eventually the same error message appears if I try to access the route to any of the controller's endpoints.

Answer (score 5):

Solved. Turns out that I wasn't supposed to include `x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()` solely on the DB Context file, but also on Startup.cs. Duh!

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabaseString"), x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()) );
```